# Vim: Configure syntastic c++ checker

Tags: c++, vim, syntastic

I have successfully installed Syntastic and I would like to use gcc as a syntax checker for c++.

The gcc.vim is in the syntax_checkers/cpp directory but it doesn't appear as an available checker when I call

```
:SyntasticInfo
```

What should I do to make it available?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

I should have installed clang first.

Comment: you can just point to it by setting the variable: let g:syntastic_c++_clang_exec = 'path/to/clang'